# Set schema to prevent nested values in mongodb in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a collection which I want to insert documents in the way that each document can have as many Fields as it wants.But this structure has a constraint.Value of each field shouldn't be nested and by nested I mean something like dictionary , list and tuple(I can't think of any other nested structure in python).

***Document Structure:***

```
{
    "field1": "value1", #value1 shouldn't be nested(list,dict,tuple) 
    "field2": "value2"  #value2 shouldn't be nested(list,dict,tuple) 
    "field3": "value3"  #value3 shouldn't be nested(list,dict,tuple) 
     ...         
}
```

Q: How can I set a schema using MongoEngine or anything like that to satisfy my condition?

Comment: So the values can be strings, numbers, booleans and None? I think it is easier to have a whitelist than a blacklist. Do you want validation at the moment the value is added to the object or at the moment of storing the object?

Comment: I want validation at the moment the values is added to object and I have some datatype like <class 'uuid.UUID'> which aren't string ,numbers ...  so I can't use whitelist

Comment: and I'm just wondering how can I set a schema to whole fields in a document(e.g set schema in the way that all fields must be string while I don't know how many field I have but I want them to be string)